# Kendo editor bind to click for cancel, update, X

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In an editor template, I have this code:

```
$('.k-grid-cancel, .k-grid-update, .k-i-close').bind('click', function (e) {
    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(colorACommandCell, 1000);
});
```

This calls my function when I click the Cancel or the Update button, but it does not call it if I click the X to close the editor.  How can I similarly catch the click of the X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attached click handler to the X of the grid popup window like this:

```
$('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.editable.element.closest('.k-window')
     .find('.k-window-action:has(.k-i-close)').click(function(){
          alert('x was clicked');
      })
```

Comment: I see that I did not say that this was a popup editor.    In my case, `editable` is undefined.  In my developer tools page, I see a span, class k-i-close, inside an anchor, class k-window-action k-link, inside a div, class k-window-actions, inside a div, class k-window-titlebar, inside a div, class k-window.  The k-window-titlebar has a sibling div, class k-popup-edit-form, which has a child div, class k-edit-form-container, which has a child div, id MyEditorTemplate. However, $('#MyEditorTemplate').closest('.k-window').length returns 0.